# How to unset field for loads of documents?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have huge table that is fully dynamic (not mapped to any POCO). It has multiple fields and one of them is named `two`. How can I remove this field for every document that has `ArchiveId` set to `1`?

I have tried getting all items and then saving each but it gives me error. I suspect that db just times out or something because it's working and running since I can get records just fine afterwards.

Note that I have over 1m records and this method that I'm doing is probably very bad but I don't know any better.

> Server instance localhost:27017 is no longer connected.

What I have tried

```
public void DeleteFieldByArchiveId(int id, string field)
{
    var collection = _db.GetCollection("items");

    collection.Find(Query.EQ("ArchiveId", id))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x =>
        {
            x[field] = null;
            collection.Save(x);
        });
}
```

## EDIT (What I need)

`db.items.update({ArchiveId: 1}, {$unset: {two : ""}}, {multi: true})`

Basically this is what I want to achieve using C# mongo driver. I just tested this query in RoboMongo and it removed all fields from 1m database in about 20 seconds without timeouts. How can I execute this query inside C# mongo driver?

Comment: How many is loads? Are you talking about a dozen or a million?

Comment: Yeah I would probably do this in batches using the timer function as stated below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the C# way of performing the query using the static `Unset` method of the `Update` class:

```
IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("Activity", 1);         
UpdateBuilder ub = Update.Unset("two");
MongoUpdateOptions options = new MongoUpdateOptions {
    Flags = UpdateFlags.Multi
};
var updateResults = examples.Update(query, ub, options);
```

This results in:

```
query = { "Activity" : 1 }
update = { "$unset" : { "two" : 1 } }
```

*(The value of `two` in the update expression doesn't matter [per the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)).*

Full example:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;

var client = new MongoClient(); // connect to localhost
var server = client.GetServer();
var test = server.GetDatabase("test");
var examples = test.GetCollection("examples");

var query = Query.EQ("Activity", 1);         
var ub = Update.Unset("two");
var options = new MongoUpdateOptions {
    Flags = UpdateFlags.Multi
};
var updateResults = examples.Update(query, ub, options);
if (updateResults != null)
{                
    Console.WriteLine(updateResults);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the code was edited to be `new UpdateBuilder().Unset`. While technically that works, it's not necessary as the static method `Unset` does the same thing, but more succinctly (and follows the pattern of `Query`). I've changed the answer back (and added the `using`s in case it wasn't clear what was being used).

Comment: For those who get confused by general namings, {test} is the {database}, and {examples} is the {collection}. Appreciate if the answer is updated conventionally.

Answer (score 3):

I am extremely rusty at C# but if you wanna do it the way your edit says then try this:

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> items;
var query = new QueryDocument {
    { "ArchiveId", 1 }
};
var update = new UpdateDocument {
    { "$unset", new BsonDocument("two", "") }
};
BsonDocument update = items.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Multi);
```

For reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#update-method

Comment: That update statement works, but only updates one document. To updated them all add `UpdateFlags.Multi` as in

`BsonDocument update = items.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Multi);`

Answer (score -2):

You may overflow the server with it. You have over 1m records so this could be it.
Try to add

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ms);
```

For ms you must look how many you need. I would start testing at 50ms.

For testing i would use:

```
for (int ms = 50; ms < 1001; ms++)
{
    try { DeleteFieldByArchiveId(id, field, ms); break; } catch { }
}

public void DeleteFieldByArchiveId(int id, string field, int TimeToWaitInMS)
{
    var collection = _db.GetCollection("items");

    collection.Find(Query.EQ("ArchiveId", id))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x =>
        {
            x[field] = null;
            collection.Save(x);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeToWaitInMS)
        });
}
```